# error: function returning a function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

Although there is at least [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033298/boostserialization-function-not-returning), I still ask mine since that one hasn't got solved and seems more complicated. I'm trying to simplify mine.

I have a .cpp file that uses .h as below, and compiling these sheds error as follows. Any idea is appreciated. Note that codes are simplified in order to minimally show the problematic parts only.

FC_boost_prove.h:

```
#ifndef FC_H
#define FC_H

#include <vector>
#include "iostream"

#include "boost/signal.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"
#include <boost/random.hpp>

typedef boost::signal0<void()> PreUpdateSignal;
typedef PreUpdateSignal::slot_function_type PreUpdateSlot;
typedef boost::signal0<void()> PostUpdateSignal;
typedef PostUpdateSignal::slot_function_type PostUpdateSlot;

class FC {
public:
    FC(uint width, uint height) {
        std::cout << "In constructor." << std::endl;
    }
    ~FC() {
        //Do ...
    }
    void connectPreUpdate(PreUpdateSlot s) {
        preUpdateSignal_.connect(s);
    }
    void connectPostUpdate(PostUpdateSlot s) {
        postUpdateSignal_.connect(s);
    }

protected:
    PreUpdateSignal preUpdateSignal_;
    PostUpdateSignal postUpdateSignal_;
};
#endif
```

FC_boost_prove.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FC_boost_prove.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "test." << std::endl;
}
```

Compile error:

```
$ g++ FC_boost_prove.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals/signal0.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signal.hpp:19,
                 from FC_boost_prove.h:7,
                 from FC_boost_prove.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/last_value.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::last_value<void()>’:
/usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:178:   instantiated from ‘boost::signal0<void(), boost::last_value<void()>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function0<void()> >’
FC_boost_prove.h:12:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/last_value.hpp:22: error: function returning a function
In file included from /usr/include/boost/signals/signal0.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signal.hpp:19,
                 from FC_boost_prove.h:7,
                 from FC_boost_prove.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::signal0<void(), boost::last_value<void()>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function0<void()> >’:
FC_boost_prove.h:12:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:330: error: function returning a function
/usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:370: error: function returning a function
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/function0.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp:38,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals/signal0.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signal.hpp:19,
                 from FC_boost_prove.h:7,
                 from FC_boost_prove.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::function0<void()>’:
FC_boost_prove.h:24:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1006: error: function returning a function
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::detail::function::basic_vtable0<void()>’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:856:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function0<R>::clear() [with R = void()]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:752:   instantiated from ‘boost::function0<R>::~function0() [with R = void()]’
/usr/include/boost/signals/slot.hpp:105:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:486: error: function returning a function
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:643: error: function returning a function
```

Environment: Ubuntu 10.10, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you specifying `boost::signal0<>`? The signal*N* templates are for deficient compilers that can't properly parse function signatures.

Either use signal and specify the function signature, as recommended for modern compilers:

```
typedef boost::signal<void()> PreUpdateSignal;
typedef boost::signal<void()> PostUpdateSignal;
```

or use signal*N* and specify the return type (and every argument type) explicitly, as needed for deficient compilers:

```
typedef boost::signal0<void> PreUpdateSignal;
typedef boost::signal0<void> PostUpdateSignal;
```

Comment: thanks. I now got my codes compiled and working. Actually eclipse still shows as error so I had to use g++ from commanline (this is another story though).